# how to convert Cell array of n*m having class as double to class uint16

Tags: matlab

```
    %Code Snippet
    load( lapFileSource, 'UntitledMeta_Data' );%MyFile
    %Code to Calculate F_27 Data
    %I Calculate Frac_ Values in above code
    F_27=horzcat(Frac_123,Frac_A, Frac_C,_Frac_D,Check_1,Check_2 );
    assignin('base','F_27',F_27);%Making it to Workspace
    % where F_27 is 2356*64 Double
```

> How to Convert F_27 from double to uint16

Comment: `F27u=uint16(F_27)` ... but if your `double`s are not integral values you are going to loose some precision, and if they are negative or >65535 the values will be saturated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a specific reason to use a cell array? For uniform data, a matrix is typically the better choice. I would use `cell2mat` first to get a matrix, then `uint16` to convert the data type.

Comment: Yes, because I want to postProcess that Variable. Also it has a time array with it which i need to trim.

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment, but if you really have to use a cell, use `cellfun(@uint16,F_27,'uniformOutput',0)` to convert to uint16

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked out. Fortunately I don't have any external exceptions. So it helped.